Replicate the VF renderAs="PDF" Functionality Using LWC
We currently have a VF page (rendered as PDF) that generates invoice data. We use it in several places in the org: it's accessible via a record action on the Invoice record page, it can be sent as an email attachment to the customer, etc.
Trying to overcome the limitation of not being able to set custom font families on renderAs="PDF" pages (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_output_pdf_supported_fonts.htm), we've been requested to implement the entire feature using LWC instead of Visualforce.
By implementing this with an LWC, we will be able to set custom fonts, but is there any way for us to attach the invoice (in PDF format) to an email, or to provide a way to download the invoice as a PDF while rendering it with LWC?

Check if this may help you.

https://www.absyz.com/how-to-generate-pdf-and-word-in-lwc-using-visualforce-page/
https://www.salesforcebolt.com/2022/01/convert-to-pdf-lightning-web-component.html


@TusharJadav Unfortunately, none of those approaches work here since they're using a VF page as the last step to generate/render the PDF. We would still hit the  SF limitation about utilizing a custom font family in VF pages configured with renderAs='PDF'

I think the presumption that LWC will somehow provide a better path to rendering a PDF is misplaced. There isn't anything in LWC that makes it inherently easier to render a PDF in a non-VF "renderAs" way.
We've gone down this road a few times, and have come to the conclusion that to render a PDF that looks good and doesn't have the limitations of "renderAs", you need to either:

create or use an off-platform PDF generation web service. We've done this in the past when the customer needed multiple rendering options (e.g. DOCX/PDF/XLS).
use a client-side JavaScript PDF generation library. Again, there isn't really a strong argument for doing this in VF or LWC, because the actual heavy lifting will be done in client-side JS code, which works in either VF or LWC. An example of a pretty nice JS library for PDF generation is here: https://pdf-lib.js.org/

I am not aware of any decent option for Salesforce-server-side PDF generation that doesn't use "renderAs=pdf", Apex just doesn't have the features to reliably create binary documents.
